# TFS 2015 failing to run selenium specflow tests

Tags: selenium, tfs, specflow

I'm struggling to get TFS 2015 to run my selenium specflow tests.  The automation is for our production environment so the TFS project doesn't need to deploy the website code, it just needs to run the automation agaist www.  (The automation code has the www address coded into it)

I've seen the chrome driver sandbox parameter although that hasn't removed my problem.  I've added the following when initializing my chrome driver, shown below

**Use of chrome sandbox**

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("–no-sandbox");  // also tried "--no-sandbox"
return new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**TFS Command line build step settings**

```
Tool: packages/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.1\tools\nunit3-console.exe
Arguments: "../../../My.Automation/bin/Debug/My.Automation.dll" --where "cat=demo
Working folder: $/UAT Automation/Dev/SourceCode
```

**Error experienced on TFS (it works locally on my machine)**

I get the same error when I run the command on the server myself.

```
Unknown error: cannot find chrome driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few ideas:

1. Check repository. Probably you didn't checkout folder with chrome
   driver (you have it locally, but not in repo)
2. You have a path to chrome driver in code, and it is different from the path in TFS server

Comment: Thanks, I've now added the chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\" to ensure the location is what I expect it is.  Logged onto the TFS server. when I execute the tests through a command prompt I get an error message "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: THe HTTP request to the remote webdriver server for url http://localhost:54015/session timedout - not sure what this address is?

Comment: I don't know how looks your environment. If you don't using selenium grid, configure it. Here is an example:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: Thanks for this, I have read through this article before without success.